# I want to create a case in salesforce from Android App

Tags: android, rest, salesforce, apex

We have a REST API in salesforce to create cases.We want to access the same API from Android/IOS App to create a case.Here my problem is authentication.

> 1. We are using OAuth 2.0 user agent flow for authentication because in username-password we need to expose username and password so we
>      don't want to use that flow to get the access token. In User Agent
>      flow should the user need to enter the password or it will authorize
>      based on authorization code?
> 2. If user need to enter the password how we will avoid because the user will be customer they don't have any password and username ,can
>      we store password and use it to for logging automatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could try exposing a public Rest API in Salesforce. So that your mobile App can do a Post request to that specific end-point, and a case can be created via Apex, based on the criteria specified in your Json.